# page outputcache not working with trace

Tags: asp.net, caching, stack-trace

I had put the following code in the .aspx page:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" Inherits="CarWale.CarDataIO.MasterDataEntry" Trace="true"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<%@ OutputCache Duration="10" VaryByParam="none" %>

<head runat="server">
<title>Master Data Entry</title>
<link href="/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div> <%= DateTime.Now.ToString() %></div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

When the above page was rendered with Trace="false", the code was running perfectly as expecting. The page was getting cached and the DateTime changed after every 10 seconds as expected.

But, when the Trace="true" was applied, all the page caching was lost and the DateTime was changing everytime the page was refreshed even before 10 seconds duration was completed. This I consider a serious bug in ASP.NET framework.

Can anybody guide me where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe it's a bug but just a consequence of tracing and allowing it to output to the page.

If you use these settings for tracing in `web.config` it should work.

```
<trace enabled="true" requestLimit="1000" localOnly="false" pageOutput="false"/>
```

Here, `pageOutput="false"` will prevent the tracing from being shown on the page directly and is now only accessible with [TraceViewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wwh16c6c.aspx). To see the trace, just append `\Trace.axd` to the url of your asp.net page (select `default.aspx` to get the same result page from before ).

With `pageOutput` disabled, tracing will now no longer prevent output caching.